# Python Programming Review

Tags: python-3.x

I searched and just found some closed threads, but I was wondering if there is anywhere that I could upload some code that I wrote, just to have someone look at it and show me what I could change or if there is another way that I could go about what I was trying to accomplish.

I have been self teaching for about 7 months and couldn't think of any programs to write for practice, then the accounting dept was saying that they wished blah, blah, blah....anyways, I decided to try to write a program for it, and I just finished it.  I'm pretty excited, but I'm sure there are things that could have been simplified....

I'm not familiar with Git or Gerrit to upload there, if there are any sites that do that (For Free) then please point me in that direction...or I can copy here, if someone is willing to take a look...

Thanks!

Comment: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for peer review on your code.